# Extract the text between the two substring in NSString

Tags: objective-c

I need to extract the all the lines between two strings like Begin and End in the NSString.

For example,

```
<some text>
Begin
line1
line2
End
<some Text>
Begin
line1
line2
End
```

I need to discard all the text that is not coming under these blocks. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See `-componentsSeparatedByString:` in the `NSString` documentation.